# Decrease the space between two or more integrals

Tags: math-mode, mathtools, mathdesign

How can I reduce the space between two or more integrals at least up to a quadruple integral, to accost them a little more, using the code below?

It is 
compilable to many people/users. Thanks to everybody.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}% Italianlanguage/hyphenation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%%%%%% Symbol integral with mathdesign %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{}{}{}}
\def\upintdots@{\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu\@cdots\mkern-4mu}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}}
\newcommand{\upiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{2}}
\newcommand{\upiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{3}}
\newcommand{\upiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{4}}
\newcommand{\upidotsint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{0}}
\newcommand{\UpMultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\upintop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\upintdots@\else\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \noexpand\upintop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [1]  mdbchr7v }{}%old 0.8
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [1]  mdbchb7v }{}%old 0.8
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{"48}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDB}{}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{MDB}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchrmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchbmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDB}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{bold}{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{128}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointctrclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{136}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\upint}{\DOTSI\upintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\upoint}{\DOTSI\upointop\ilimits@}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Nuovo \partial
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{nxlmi}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
  <8.6->    nxlmi0
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlbmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlbmi07
  <8.6->    nxlbmi0
}{}


\begin{document}
\[\upiint\displaylimits_D f(x,y)dxdy,\quad \upiint_D f(x,y)dxdy\upiiint_D f(x,y,z)dxdydz\upidotsint_D f(x,y,z)dxdydz\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try changing the kerning in the first line after `\makeatletter`. For example, `\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-7mu}{}{}{}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the `mtpro2` or `classico` packages installed, so I can't reproduce your code exactly. However, it seems you can get the desired output by changing the kerning in your definition of `\upinterkern`.

Using your values

```
\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{}{}{}}
```

[image]

After changing `-3.5mu` to `-7mu`

```
\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-7mu}{}{}{}}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't worry for you can't reproduce my code exactly. Done and it works well! Thank you very much much. But was my question ugly? Apparently you only considered it yourself. I upvote you and accept it. But do you use MAC? Your screenshot is very good.

Comment: @Sebastiano People don't want to troubleshoot code, so if your MWE doesn't compile many people won't bother. And yes, I use a Mac, but more importantly the screenshot format is .png instead of .jpg.